# CMD/Windows shell - find and state program using port

Tags: winapi, shell, scripting

This is more of a Win32 shell programming question - the intention is to have a single line/piped command that will give me the application that is using a certain port -

I have 2 shell commands and I want to combine/pipe them together:

```
netstat -aon | findstr 0.0:80
wmic PROCESS get Caption,ProcessId | findstr <process_id_here>
```

The first command gives me the processID that is using port 80 on my machine e.g. "12345"
The second command gives me the name of the process if I give "12345" in

I am not sure how to combine then - can I pipe the processID to the second command? Can this be done in one line... And how...

Thanks
- Sami

Answer (score 2):

Adding the `-b` argument to the `netstat` command will also give the name of the executable that has the port open.

```
netstat -aonb
```

**Update**

There's no way to pipe the two commands together because to do that the second command has to accept in Standard Input the results of the first command on Standard Output.  In your example this is not the case.

One possibility for doing this kind of thing is to use the `for /f` command and it's ability to tokenise the output of a command to assign bits of the output to variables which can then be used in another command.  The problem here is that the pipe character can't be used in the command whose output is processed by the `for` command.  You can do what you want, though, in only one line, albeit a rather scary one:

```
for /f "tokens=2,5" %i in ('netstat -aon') do @(if "%i"=="0.0.0.0:80" (wmic PROCESS get Caption,ProcessId | findstr "%j"))
```

This line executes the `netstat -aon` command and then for each line of the output it does the following:

- Splits the line into tokens using spaces as the delimiter
- Assigns tokens 2 and 5 to variables %i (listeing address:port) and %j (process-id)
- Checks if `%i` is the string for the port you're after
- If so, runs the wmic command and filters the output based on %j

**Another Update**

I just discovered that it is possible to use a piped command in the `for` command.  So here's a slightly simpler one-liner, that basically does exactly what you're asking:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=5" %i in (`"netstat -aon | findstr "0.0:80""`) do @wmic PROCESS get Caption,ProcessId | findstr "%i"
```

Comment: thanks, that gives the processName - but as indicated above, I am more curious about how to chain the 2 commands - this is something I haven't come across via Google...